# HttpWebRequest and Parallel.ForEach causes time out after spawning certain number of threads

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, timeout, parallel.foreach

I have ran into a problem and I am searching for the best way to handle it. I am using HttpWebRequest in a Parallel.ForEach loop (the code is below). I have tested the program on more than two dozen machines and a number of different types of connections and it had worked flawlessly until now.

Today, my ADSL modem died and was replaced by the ISP with a new one - now, when I run the program and as soon as the spawned threads get to 35-40, all I get is time outs; at that point, even when I try to load the websites in my browser, they time out.

My guess is that the modem cannot handle the concurrent connections - the question is how do I prevent this from happening? Of course, I can cap the number of concurrent connections, but there should be a better way to handle this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
string pageContent;
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webSiteUrl);
myReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)";

myReq.Method = "GET";
myReq.Accept = "text/html";

myReq.Timeout = webRequestTimeout; //set to generous 90 seconds
myReq.ReadWriteTimeout = webRequestTimeout;  //set to 90 seconds


HttpWebResponse myres = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myres.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
{
    pageContent = sr.ReadToEnd();

}

myres.Close();
```

Comment: No, capping the number of concurrent connections is probably the way to go. It's simple enough to do using a `Semaphore`.

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.ForEach()` can be good at guessing the right degree of parallelism for CPU-bound operations, but with IO-bound operations, it will most likely use a degree of parallelism that's much higher than ideal. I think 40 threads is way too much, especially on a slower connection.

What you should do is to set [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) to a number that works well for you, most likely much smaller than 40.

Comment: On 4 of my computers, the number of threads spawn range from 60 on my oldest PC to 130 on my newest dual-core one and the program works just fine when I am using my cable Internet. However, any user that have their router concurrent connections capped might run into the same problem. Probably the best workaround would be to add the option for the users themselves to cap the number of connections my program runs to 10, 20, 30 etc. and then set MaxDegreeOfParallelism to the respective number. Thank you both for your answers